# Difference between webview in Fragment and webviewfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

Can anyone explain the differences between webView in fragment and webViewFragment?

Are they both the same or they are different?

Comment: WebView extends View and webViewFragment extends Fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real difference. The only difference according the docs is:

> The WebView is automically paused or resumed when the Fragment is
>   paused or resumed.